# 407 error when doing XMLHttpRequest (cross-origin) on Chrome extension background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-407

I am developing a chrome extension, and XMLHttpRequest (cross-origin) GET at any urls on backgournd script is generating following error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 407 ()
: proxy authentication required
```

When I made XMLHttpRequest (cross-origin) on content script, it worked very well without 407 error. So I am assuming it has something to do with background script proxy settings, which I have not touched at all.

**manifest**

```
"permissions": [ "<all_urls>" ]
```

**background.js**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", 'http://no-aesthetic.tumblr.com/post/110309507078', false)
xhr.send()                      //or any random urls

var result = xhr.responseText
console.log(result)
```

I know synchronous calls are deprecated, but this is just for testing purpose. I have tried asynchronous calls as well without any success.

Comment: Have you looked up what a 407 error means? Have you compared the two requests using the Developer Tools Network tab to see what is different about them? Have you looked at the server side code to see why it might be generating a 407 error?

Comment: I just know that 407 error means proxy authentication is not valid. I just compared the difference between the two requests but have not found anything meaningful. I can upload the request details from Network tab if you want to look at them. Sever side code does not matter because I am making requests to random 3rd party urls.

Comment: I just found out that the request header from background script does not have Proxy-Authorization part that the request header from content script has. Any ideas on how to implement the Proxy-Authorization manually?